# purtest and psacf: How to test it in R?

Tags: r, panel-data, stationarity, fixed-effects-model, unit-root

I am working with balanced panel data (annual country level data: 37 countries and 11 years) and would like to test stationarity. I am using fixed effects for both country and year. Now, I am checking if there's the issue of non-stationarity. However, I'm quite unsure how to do this in R.

Since I have 11 years, I entered **lag.max = 11**. I've entered the following code and got the following results:

```
#Auto- and Cross- Covariance and -Correlation Function Estimation for Panel-Series. 
psacf(output, GDPcapitaPPP ~ countryIdentifier, ~year, lag.max = 11, plot = TRUE)
```

`psacf` is from package `collapse`. From this plot, I get the idea that there is a time trend going on.
[image]

Then, I ran `purtest` (from R package `plm`) and got the following results. However, I have to say that I don't understand which options I should use after **exo** and **test**.

```
#unit root test for panel data. H0: no stationarity, H1: stationarity. Low p-value speaks in favour of H1.
library(plm)
outputpanel <- pdata.frame(output, index=c("countryIdentifier","year"))
purtest(outputpanel$GDPcapitaPPP, pmax = 3,  exo = "trend", test = "madwu")
```

The results from `purtest` suggest that my panel data is stationary. How can it be? This would be a contradiction to the plot above, right?

[image]

Comment: At first sight this looks like a question on how to use R but there is also a question here about statistics. Editing the post to be more of the latter would help, that is: what would you still be asking if you used other software?